# Vline.js is giving cryptic error message

Tags: javascript, webrtc, vline

I am trying the room example of vline and getting a cryptic error message which is am not able to figure out.

Please see the exception stack below.

```
    vline.js?t=1231:732
Local stream: W91AhWvMK6ohUoNi meeting:108
User came online, starting mediasession with: bakbak:biplav.saraf@gmail.com meeting:123
 [140623 12:31:36.22] [vline.person] Cannot read property 'log' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'log' of undefined
    at Qh.f (https://static.vline.com/vline.js?t=1231:195:297)
    at oh (https://static.vline.com/vline.js?t=1231:187:418)
    at W.n.dispatchEvent (https://static.vline.com/vline.js?t=1231:186:432)
    at W.n.vj (https://static.vline.com/vline.js?t=1231:194:348)
    at W.n.dispatchEvent (https://static.vline.com/vline.js?t=1231:193:416)
    at Kl (https://static.vline.com/vline.js?t=1231:366:162)
    at W.n.start (https://static.vline.com/vline.js?t=1231:358:142)
    at bm.n.Oe (https://static.vline.com/vline.js?t=1231:374:279)
    at startPeerMediaSession (http://localhost:5000/schedule/meeting:93:26)
    at bm.<anonymous> (http://localhost:5000/schedule/meeting:124:13)
 vline.js?t=1231:132
Be vline.js?t=1231:132
ze.Vs vline.js?t=1231:132
n.log vline.js?t=1231:127
Qh.f vline.js?t=1231:195
oh vline.js?t=1231:187
n.dispatchEvent vline.js?t=1231:186
n.vj vline.js?t=1231:194
n.dispatchEvent vline.js?t=1231:193
Nh vline.js?t=1231:194
n.xn vline.js?t=1231:384
oh vline.js?t=1231:187
n.dispatchEvent vline.js?t=1231:186
n.vj vline.js?t=1231:194
n.vj vline.js?t=1231:201
n.dispatchEvent vline.js?t=1231:193
Nh vline.js?t=1231:194
S vline.js?t=1231:207
ci vline.js?t=1231:206
mi vline.js?t=1231:209
n.kr vline.js?t=1231:439
Fo vline.js?t=1231:471
Go.send vline.js?t=1231:471
(anonymous function) vline.js?t=1231:488
$a.forEach.d vline.js?t=1231:75
sp vline.js?t=1231:488
(anonymous function) vline.js?t=1231:500
xh vline.js?t=1231:189
```

Is it possible to get unminified version of this file?

Answer (score 1):

On further debugging i figured out that i was using a global variable which was conflicting with vline.js.